# In C++, sorting a vector of big struct would be slow?

Tags: c++, vector

I thought when sorting a vector of structs, the struct elements would be moved around, or the copy-constructor would be called, which will bring in some overhead, so it should be slow.

For example,

```cpp
struct big_struct_t {
  // with many data members, just to name a few
  int val;
  vector<string> strs;
  ...
};

int main() {
  vector<big_struct_t> V;
  ... // populate V with 10k elements for example

  sort(V.begin(), V.end(), [](const big_struct_t& lhs, const big_struct_t& rhs) {
    return lhs.val < rhs.val;
  });
}
```

But after testing the above code, seems like no copy-constructor called at all during sorting. So I wonder how the `sort` actually works? It doesn't need to move the elements around at all inside the vector?

Comment: Can't say for sure without seeing `big_struct_t`, but likely it's move compatible.

Comment: Elements are not necessarily copied; where possible, they are moved. And your struct can in fact be moved efficiently (since `std::vector` can be). The actual contents of all those vectors stay put; only pointers to them are shuffled around.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I see, so I don't even need to define a custom function to move them? The compiler would generate a default move function for my struct?

Comment: @StephenNewell How to judge if the struct is move-able or not?

Comment: Yes, if no copy or move constructor is provided by the user, the compiler would attempt to [define one implicitly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor#Implicitly-declared_move_constructor)

Comment: [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) has std::is_move_constructible and std::is_move_assignable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks for the pointer! BTW, a super dumb question is how to know if compiler successfully defines one for me or not? What if my struct is very complicated?

Comment: @Eljay Interesting, so by type_traits I could actually know if the compiler could generate a default move constructor for the struct? Sounds amazing then.

Comment: @avocado -- The compiler has to generate the code, thus the compiler knows everything about the layout of the structs and classes you have.  That's why `type_traits` works.

Comment: Note that modern CPUs are extremely fast at copying memory from one location to another; so even if you had e.g. a `struct big_struct {int bigArray[5000];}` or similar you might find that `sort()` was still fairly fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the comments said, the performance of `std::sort` is highly dependent on the elements.

`std::vector` stores elements contiguously. The only way to change the order of elements is to change their values, by copying, moving or swapping them.

`std::sort` works by comparing and swapping elements in a random-accessible range (such as a `std::vector`), which, consequently, must also satisfy [ValueSwappable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ValueSwappable).

In other words, the elements must either have a member function called `swap`, or be both [MoveConstructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveConstructible) and [MoveAssignable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/MoveAssignable) (in order for `std::swap` to be used). The compiler will automatically generate both [move constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) and [move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment), unless you explicitly delete them or a member of your struct causes them to be deleted (such as [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex)). Although you can use `std::is_move_constructible` and `std::is_move_assignable` to check, you don't normally need to worry about that.

**SMALL CORRECTION** (thanks to @FrançoisAndrieux): an object can still be MoveConstructible and/or MoveAssignable, as long as it has a copy constructor and copy assignment operator (unusual, but possible). See their comment.

Since `std::sort` will swap elements, the faster instances of your struct can be swapped, the faster the algorithm can run. But, how do you know how complex that is?

If your struct contains only numeric, pointer and other easily swappable members, it should be pretty fast to swap. That also includes most STL containers, such as `std::vector`, `std::deque`, `std::list`, etc..., because they dynamically allocate their elements and simply store pointers to them. Thus, swapping them is as simple as (internally) swapping pointers to the elements.

Therefore, as long as your `big_struct_t` only contains stuff that can be quickly swapped, `std::swap` should also work fast.

You may, however, also have members that cannot be quickly swapped, such as C-arrays or `std::array`s, or have way too many members. Is this case, you may be better off using another type of container.

Containers such as `std::list` are able to reorder elements without having to swap their contents, which causes the performance of a sorting operation on one of these containers not to depend on the elements.

To demonstrate, I wrote a quick benchmark. Suppose you have the structs:

```cpp
struct big_struct_t {
  int val;
  std::vector<std::string> strs;

  bool operator<(const big_struct_t& x) const {
    return val < x.val;
  }
};

struct bigger_struct_t : big_struct_t {
  std::array<std::uint8_t, 1024> kiloByteArray;
};
```

The first one is pretty trivial to swap. The second one is not. Let's try sorting `std::vector`s and `std::list`s of 1000 `big_struct_t` and `bigger_struct_t`.

```cpp
template <typename T>
static T newContainer() {
  int i = 1000;
  T v(i);

  for (auto& struc : v)
  {
    struc.val = i;
    struc.strs.emplace_back(std::to_string(i));
    i--;
  }

  return v;
}

static void SortVectorOfBigStruct(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    auto v = newContainer<std::vector<big_struct_t>>();
    state.ResumeTiming();
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(SortVectorOfBigStruct);

static void SortVectorOfBiggerStruct(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    auto v = newContainer<std::vector<bigger_struct_t>>();
    state.ResumeTiming();
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(v);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(SortVectorOfBiggerStruct);

static void SortListOfBigStruct(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    auto l = newContainer<std::list<big_struct_t>>();
    state.ResumeTiming();
    l.sort();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(l);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(SortListOfBigStruct);

static void SortListOfBiggerStruct(benchmark::State& state) {
  for (auto _ : state) {
    state.PauseTiming();
    auto l = newContainer<std::list<bigger_struct_t>>();
    state.ResumeTiming();
    l.sort();
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(l);
  }
}

BENCHMARK(SortListOfBiggerStruct);
```

[image: Benchmark results]

[Benchmark on quick-bench.com](https://www.quick-bench.com/q/WnCCvVYN0krGiSdkV7JaQR51CIA).

As you can see, sorting a `std::vector<bigger_struct_t>` is 49x slower than `std::vector<big_struct_t>`, due to the `std::array`.

Sorting both `std::list<bigger_struct_t>` and `std::list<big_struct_t>` is much faster than `std::vector<bigger_struct_t>`, since they don't have to deal with the `std::array`.

Both are also considerably slower than `std::vector<big_struct_t>`, so avoid using `std::list` unless you need to.

PS: I'm not sure why `std::list<bigger_struct_t>` is slower than `std::list<big_struct_t>`. Maybe a problem with the benchmark? **NOTE:** See @FrançoisAndrieux's comment about the likely culprit being cache misses.

Comment: The list of bigger objects is probably slower since you can fit fewer elements in a cache line and likely have more cache misses. Hardware considerations like cache hits, branch prediction and memory locality usually dominate performance unless extremely large data sets are considered. This is why `std::vector` so often appears faster than other types even when though algorithmic complexity would predict otherwise.

Comment: Note a move constructer and move `operator=` are not required for a type to be MoveAssignable or MoveConstructible. A copy constructor and copy `operator=` can be sufficient (but not ideal).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux You said *bigger objects is probably slower* in your first comment, which actually confuses me, because as said in this answer, `vector<big_object_type>` only stores the pointers to those `big_object_type` allocated, right? If so, swapping elements of a vector is just like swapping pointers, should be very fast, regardless of how big `big_object_type` is, no?

Comment: Thanks very much for such a detailed answer!!!! 1 follow-up question, `std::vector<bigger_struct_t>` is much slower due to the `array` member, so in this case would it be great to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<bigger_struct_t>>`?  (the motivation is I just want to avoid `list`)

Comment: @avocado Yes, that'd be much faster, at least in theory. EDIT: But note that initialization would probably take considerably longer, since you'd be allocating memory for each element.

Comment: A couple more follow-up questions:   
(1) *such as C-arrays or std::array* cannot be quickly swapped, why? I thought both have pointers to the allocated memory, and if so we can swap that pointer, no?    
(2)  *have way too many members* would make the struct un-swappable? why?

Comment: *take considerably longer, since you'd be allocating memory for each element*, why would this be a problem at the first place?  No matter using `unique_ptr` or not, the elements are always created somewhere (i.e. memory allocated somehwere), I don't see why using `unique_ptr` to allocate memory would be an issue.

Comment: @avocado Members like `int data[100];` or`std::array<int, 100>` store the elements within them, they aren't pointers. Their size are `sizeof(int) * 100` and to move them you need to copy them completely.

Comment: @avocado (1) No. Unlike other containers, arrays don't allocate data dynamically. The data is stored in the struct itself. Try looking at the `sizeof` of a large `std::vector` and a large `std::array` or C-array. The `std::vector` will be constant with size, the others will not. (2) Having way too many members would not make it un-swappable, but it would take longer, since it'd have to swap each member.

Comment: @avocado (3) Not exactly, element construction takes the same amount of time, but memory allocation will be slower. A `std::vector<T>` will allocate memory everytime it needs to grow. A `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` will allocate memory everytime it needs to grow AND ALSO for each element.

Comment: Also, I can't edit my comment anymore, but, to be more accurate: The data is stored in the array, which in turn is stored in the struct.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux and LHLaurini, thank you both very much, new lessons learned!